# list of dictionary from object - taking single value from field

Tags: jquery

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "this is good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "hat i like"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "because must be good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "another good thing"}}]
```

Is there possibility to append to some DOM element single value from one of dictionary from my list. For example, how to select `"pk":1` from this list?

Comment: are you trying to select '"pk":1' from the sttring/list or trying to get the value of 'pk'?

Comment: trying to get "pk: 1" from array like above

Comment: Where does the DOM factor into the data you showed us? What is "some DOM element single value"? What do you mean by "select"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the first object in the main Array by index `[0]`, then access the value of the `pk` property via `.pk`.

```
var arr = [{"pk": 1, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "this is good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "hat i like"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "because must be good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "another good thing"}}];

alert( arr[0].pk );  // 1
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FBjuW/

...or you could loop over the outer Array to get the `pk` value at each index.

```
for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    alert( arr[ i ].pk );
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FBjuW/1/

I don't know what DOM element you're talking about, but you can append the resulting value to your element if you need.

---

**EDIT:**

If you're doing a DOM selection, and need to append the `pk` value per result found, you could do this:

```
$('.mySelector').append(function( i ) { return arr[ i ].pk; });
```

This uses the [`append()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method and passes a function to it. The return value is the value that gets appended.

The `i` parameter represents the index number of the current matched element during the iteration.

Comment: But for example if i get data objects by jetJSON, can I just treat it like array?

Comment: @Cris: Yes, if you're using `getJSON`, then jQuery will make sure the text result gets parsed into the proper JavaScript structure.

Comment: ...I can emulate this behavior by making your markup into a String, and using `$.parseJSON` to parse it into the desired structures. http://jsfiddle.net/nCg7H/

Comment: Than thakns a lot. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can access the value of each 'pk':

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    if(value.pk)
        alert(value.pk);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to get the value of 'pk' should be able to use the string like and object. 
You may have to do some converting using JSON and stringify.

The string represents an object.
Each set of {} is another object wiht its own properties.

```
var o = [{"pk": 1, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "this is good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "hat i like"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "social.thing", "fields": {"content": "because must be good", "visible": true, "user": 1, "parent": [2], "title": "another good thing"}}];

alert(o.pk);
alert(o.fields[0].title);
```